# Making layers untrainable at end of epoch changes loss in next epoch

Tags: keras, layer, freeze

I wrote a custom callback to automatically freeze layers in my multi input/output network in case the corresponding loss falls below a certain threshold.

How it works: After every epoch it checks if the loss of the first weight in self.weights is below the self.loss_thresholds value. If so, it freezes the corresponding layers and makes the underlying layers trainable. After that it sets the models stop_training flag in order to exit the fit function and to recompile the model.

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class WeightLossCallback(Callback):

def __init__(self, loss_weights):
    self.loss_weights = loss_weights
    self.weights = ["akVol","biltarres","riskap1","sraj","zbj"]
    self.loss_thresholds = {"akVol": 0.12, "biltarres": 0.12, "riskap1": 0.14, "sraj": 1.5, "zbj": 14.}
    self.learning_rate = {"akVol": 0.05, "biltarres": 0.05, "riskap1": 0.05, "sraj": 0.01, "zbj": 0.05}
    self.stopTraining=False

def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
    K.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, self.learning_rate[self.weights[0]])

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):

    if epoch < 10:
        return

    def freezeAttAndLayer(weight):
        print("Setting weight " + weight + " to zero.")
        self.weights.remove(weight)
        self.loss_weights[weight] = 0.0
        self.stopTraining=True

        print("Step 2: Freezing corresponding layers.")        
        for layer in self.model.layers:
            if weight in layer.name:
                print("Freezing layer " + layer.name + ".")
                layer.trainable=False

    def unfreezeAttAndLayer(weight):
        print("Step 3: Unfreezing corresponding layers.")        
        self.loss_weights[nextWeight] = 1000.
        for layer in self.model.layers:
            if weight in layer.name:
                print("Unfreezing layer " + layer.name + ".")
                layer.trainable=True

    # in case of last weight in self.weights list
    if len(self.weights) < 2:
        lastWeight = self.weights[0]
        if logs[lastWeight+"_loss"] >= self.loss_thresholds[lastWeight]:
            return
        else:
            freezeAttAndLayer(lastWeight)
            self.model.stop_training=True
            return

    currentWeight = self.weights[0]
    nextWeight = self.weights[1]
    print("Step 1: Checking weight thresholds for " + currentWeight + " and " + nextWeight + "...")

    if logs[currentWeight+"_loss"] < self.loss_thresholds[currentWeight]:
        freezeAttAndLayer(currentWeight)
        unfreezeAttAndLayer(nextWeight)

    if self.stopTraining:
        self.stopTraining=False
        self.model.stop_training=True
        print(self.loss_weights)
        print(self.weights)
```

The fit function works as follows:

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
ModelCpt = ModelCheckpoint("C:/Users/pan11811/Desktop/ModelCheckpoint/test.h5", monitor="loss",save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False)
WeightLossCpt = WeightLossCallback(loss_weights)

epochCount=0
while(i<21):
ReduceLRCpt = ReduceLROnPlateau(patience=35, min_delta=0.1, factor=0.6, monitor=WeightLossCpt.weights[0]+"_loss", verbose=1, min_lr=0.001)
model.fit(inputDic, outputDic, epochs=2000+epochCount,batch_size=4000, callbacks=[ReduceLRCpt,ModelCpt,WeightLossCpt], verbose=1)
   model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adamax(lr=0.025),loss=losses.mean_squared_error,loss_weights=Weig htLossCpt.loss_weights)
epochCount+=1    
if len(WeightLossCpt.weights) == 0:
    print("Training completed.")
    break

print("#######################################")
print("RECOMPILED_MODEL")
print("#######################################")
```

Here is the training log for freezing the sraj net:

```
    Epoch 968/2003
    64538/64538 [==============================] - 0s 5us/step - loss: 1489.0058 -    tbaRenormalized_loss: 11.6664 - tbasum_loss: 180.4811 - vtstkj_loss: 0.0000e+00 - sraj_loss: 1.4885 - riskap1_loss: 0.1149 - biltarres_loss: 0.1144 - akVol_loss: 0.1210 - zbj_loss: 60316658.7545 - zb_loss: 18562112.8038 - sra_output_loss: 0.4971 - vtstk_loss: 0.0000e+00
Step 1: Checking weight thresholds for sraj and zbj...
Setting weight sraj to zero.
Step 2: Freezing corresponding layers.
Freezing layer input_sraj.
Freezing layer sraj_0.
Freezing layer sraj_1.
Freezing layer sraj_2.
Freezing layer sraj_3.
Freezing layer sraj_4.
Freezing layer sraj_5.
Freezing layer sraj.
Step 3: Unfreezing corresponding layers.
Unfreezing layer zbj.
{'tbaRenormalized': 0.0, 'tbasum': 0.0, 'sraj': 0.0, 'riskap1': 0.0, 'zb': 0.0, 'biltarres': 0.0, 'akVol': 0.0, 'vtstk': 0.0, 'zbj': 1000.0}
['zbj']

#######################################
RECOMPILED_MODEL
#######################################
Epoch 1/2004
64538/64538 [==============================] - 0s 6us/step - loss: 18151638696.1287 - tbaRenormalized_loss: 11.6664 - tbasum_loss: 180.4811 - vtstkj_loss: 0.0000e+00 - sraj_loss: 2.5473 - riskap1_loss: 0.1149 - biltarres_loss: 0.1144 - akVol_loss: 0.1210 - zbj_loss: 18151638.7103 -    zb_loss: 5467256.6113 - sra_output_loss: 0.9667 - vtstk_loss: 0.0000e+00
```

The problem here is that right before freezing the layers, sraj loss is below threshold at 1.4885 but after freezing and recompiling the network the loss jumps to 2.5473, but it remains constant.

So my question is, why does this jump occur when I clearly froze all layers?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Is there any update on a solution for this?